# New Site Column is not being displayed insdie Sharepoint Designer Toolbox

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, site-column

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection. and i added a new site column of type managed metadata. then i opned the sharePoint designer , but i can not find the new site column inside the toolbox. can anyone advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this would work! But have you tried restarting SharePoint designer? Do you find the Site Column when you navigate to the site?

Comment: yes the site column is inside the site collection , when i access the "site setting->site columns" from CA. but even after restarting the SP designer the site column is not being displayed inside the toolbox..

Comment: @Plexus81 i try restarting the SharePoint designer,and i also restart the server itself but this did not help ..